# How can I query a Google Spreadsheet tab using SQL filtering results by other tab data

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I'm working with SQL queries inside Google Spreadsheets and I have a simple query that's not working. Basically, I have two tabs called `Apps` and `Pricing`, and I need to populate a column of the `Apps` based on a query inside `Pricing`, using a column in `Apps` as the `WHERE` filter.

That's how I tried to write it, I couldn't find the syntax specification for this in the documentation. Replacing the `Apps!D6` for the hardcoded text it's working, but I need it to be dynamic.

```
=QUERY(Pricing!C5:K9,"SELECT I where C=`Apps!D6`, -1)")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=QUERY(Pricing!C5:K9,"SELECT I where C='" & Apps!D6 & "'",-1)
```

to debug query formula, try entering query text in separate cell, like A1:

```
="SELECT I where C='" & Apps!D6 & "'"
```

And the query will be simplified to `=QUERY(Pricing!C5:K9, A1, -1)`

Comment: Great! Worked nicely.